# how to know the circuit is minimum or not？

Tags: minimum, circuit, karnaugh-map

1.When using a karnaugh map to simplify a circuit，how to know if the circuit is minimum or not？

2.If the expression can be turned into multi-level，how to know how many levels could be minimum circuit？(minimum "inputs" and "gates")

Comment: iirc as long as you set up the karnough map correctly and correctly find each grouping you are interested in (minterms and/or maxterms) you will have the minimum. but SO is def not the right site to ask that question, you might want engineering, computer science, or mathematics SE's

Answer (score 1):

**Optimality for two-level design:**
In a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), there may be [prime implicants](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prime_implicant) which cover [minterms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minterm) not covered by any other [implicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicant). These are called *[essential](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digital-logic-implicants-k-map/)*, as they have to be part of any selection of prime implicants which represents the circuit.

Non-essential prime implicancts may or may not be part of the selected cover. There is a choice, which non-essential one(s) to pick. Therefore, it is not always obvious, how many prime implicants have to be selected to cover all minterms. But in practical cases with only four or fewer input variables, there is typically little doubt. However, in general cases with many input variables, the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) to solve can take arbitrarily long.

**Multilevel is much harder:**
[Multilevel logic synthesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2984277_Multilevel_logic_synthesis) is a research topic since decades. No algorithm is known which always finds an optimal circuit.

The optimization criteria vary depending on the application. Number of gate levels may be less relevant than the physical time delay between input and output change. The delay in turn depends on the gate technology being used and the [fan-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out) of gate inputs driven. Other criteria include chip area and number of [74xx-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400-series_integrated_circuits) integrated circuits required.